# EJB or Struts application require server to run the application?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, struts2, ejb

> The EJB or Struts application require server to run the application but Spring framework doesn't require server.

I don't understand the above one-liner.

Are they talking about web applications ?

And all web applications require a server. Am I Correct ?

Please explain . I am begineer in Spring

Comment: First of all are you clear with what do you mean by a web application and a standalone application? If yes, are you aware of web servers and application servers?

Comment: I suppose this refers more to spring Boot and itsvfeature to embed a servlet engine like Tomcat, Jetty or Undertow within an executable jar versus a war to be deployed in let's say Tomcat or a full blown JEE server.

Comment: EJB only works on Java EE servers, Struts runs everywhere, Spring runs everywhere, what is the question?

Comment: The EJB or Struts application require server to run the application but Spring framework doesn't require server.

The above sentence is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I googled that weird sentence out of curiosity, and I've discovered you've taken it from [this blog](http://www.visionsdeveloper.com/tutorial/spring/what-is-spring.jsp).

That is a fascinating amount of vagueness, imprecision and unasked boldness.

Spring is a *world*. 

Today, saying *Spring* is like saying *Apache*. 
Struts2 is Apache, Log4J2 is Apache, but one can't say *Apache is an MVC framework* or *Apache is a logging framework*.

Spring is a framework in the sense it is a collection of tools, amongst which there is Spring MVC, an alternative to Struts2. But, if I should guess what the author was trying to say with

> The EJB or Struts application require server to run the application but Spring framework doesn't require server.

, I suppose it was referring to the fact that, using Spring Beans and some other jars, you can achieve *dependency injections*, *scoping*, *transactions* etc. using a simple Servlet Container (like Tomcat or Jetty), without the need to run on a full EE Container (like JBoss/Wildfly, Glassfish, Weblogic, TomEE,...).

But in the end, who cares ? Just stop reading random stuff, and pay more attention when choosing the right sources of knowledge, especially when you're a newbie on the topic.